# C++ Visual Studio 13 using threads: minimal example not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013

i got a minimal example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/
for the implementation of threads.

Unfortunately this example did not compile and ERROR C2664 is thrown:

```
// thread example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread

void foo() 
{
  // do stuff...
}

void bar(int x)
{
  // do stuff...
}

int main() 
{
  std::thread first (foo);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()
  std::thread second (bar,0);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0)

  std::cout << "main, foo and bar now execute concurrently...\n";

  // synchronize threads:
   first.join();                // pauses until first finishes
  second.join();               // pauses until second finishes

  std::cout << "foo and bar completed.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

error C2664: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)' : 
cannot convert argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::thread &&'

Can someone explain what ist wrong with the example // with Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, works with VS2012

Comment: It works with VS2015 too, are you **sure** this is **exactly** the code you are compiling?  Which line does the error refer to? Why does the error refer to "argument n" when there is nothing called "n" in your program?

Comment: Suspicion: you wrote `foo()` instead of `foo` in your actual code.

Comment: sorry, argument n is actually thrown as argument 1

Comment: error relates to                              std::thread first (foo);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code works in VS 2013 (but also in VS 2012, VS 2015).

Try to create a new project and copy the code there. VS behaves strange sometimes. Also removing the `.sdf` file may help together with "build -> clean solution".